# React JS, props validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to React JS, props validation practise as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
     return (
        <div>
           <h3>String : {this.props.propstring}</h3>
        </div>
     );
  }
}
App.propTypes = {
   propstring : PropTypes.string
}
App.defaultProps = {
   propstring : "My Name"
}

export default App;
```

```
import React, { component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './AppProp.js';

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Getting an error as:

> TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null.

What am I missing here and how can I resolve the above error?

Comment: Is the `App` class component present in the file `AppProp.js`?

Comment: `import React, { component } from 'react';` component should be in first upper

Comment: @Roy.B No, that's not the issue as he's using `React.Component`.

Comment: @RameshReddy not in his index.js

Comment: Yep, he can remove that unused import.

Comment: which unused import?

Comment: Your issue is not reproducible, the code works fine when set up in a sandbox. I'd start by making sure that all your imports are properly/actually installed.

Comment: It worked when removing unused imports

Answer (score 0):

The code is perfectly fine. I executed it on my local machine and it ran fine.

The only issue you may be facing is to with

> circularly importing classes, which is apparently a limitation

Know more from the resource:

https://esdiscuss.org/topic/how-to-solve-this-basic-es6-module-circular-dependency-problem

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible problems. Most probably you're importing `{ component }`(like you do in your index file, which is wrong), instead of `{ Component }` somewhere in your code and trying to `extend component` which doesn't exist.
The other reason is that you might be circularly importing classes, but I doubt it. Also, is your file called `AppProp.js`?

Post the stack trace and it would also help if you post all the components you're using. Post your package.json as well, as you might be using wrong absolute paths.

Comment: I didn't post all my code, so sorry for that. problem arise from one of the import class component which have error. and i got the answer. thanks anyway